# Azure Data Factory Oracle Source with date variable

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am building a logical data warehouse. Source is Oracle and Destination is Data Lake. Initial load is done with ADF reading data from On Prem Oracle server and Parquet files created to serve as database. Now I need to add functionality of incremental data loading.

1- I have added a Lookup to start with, in which LDW is queried to get the last date.

2- Used a Set Variable activity to set the variable with the date

3- Copy Activity to read data starting from the date + 1 and up to SYSDATE -1. This task is failing as I am unable to build the where the clause properly ( I am new to ADF). My current Where clause is this

```
WHERE  TO_DATE(si.schedule_date, 'YYYYMMDD') 
BETWEEN to_date('formatDateTime('@{variables('LastDate')}', 'yyyyMMdd')','YYYYMMDD') 
AND  SYSDATE-1
```

Error I am getting is this:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis,Source=msora28.dll,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. I am stuck on this for quite long and trying to get out of confusion.
Thanks

Comment: `schedule_date` is a date column ? If so, why are you using `to_date` over a date column ?

Comment: no. its char(8) and date stored in it as yyyymmdd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there is some syntax error after ADF parsing your oracle query.

You may want to try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_item si
WHERE TO_DATE(si.schedule_date, 'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('@{variables('LastDate')}', 'yyyymmdd') AND SYSDATE-1
```

Make sure `@{}` is associated with `variables('LastDate')`; and the expression is single quoted

Comment: Thx so much for taking time. schedule_date is by the way a CHAR(8) field. My whole statement is. I didnt use Add Dynamic Content, just copied as is in Query window.

select * from schedule_item si 
WHERE TO_DATE(si.schedule_date, 'yyyymmdd') 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('@{variables('LastDate')}', 'yyyymmdd') AND SYSDATE-1 
Error is:
ORA-00936: missing expression

If I use @concat in Add dynamic content, The whole pipeline doesnt work, not just this step.
The error message isnt really very helpful. 

By the way similar statement when run against the SQL Server, run fine without any problem.

Comment: @KashifZia I have updated the expression to better fit your case. Please have a try and let us know the result. `@concat` probably wont work and in my opinion, make your expression more hard to maintain and easier to break.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a missing parenthesis. Make sure you close the parenthesis rightly.

And , I'm assuming the schedule date is a date column.. try this out ?

@Concat('select part of query ',
'WHERE  si.schedule_date BETWEEN '  , formatDateTime({variables('LastDate')}, 'yyyyMMdd') ,
' AND  SYSDATE-1')

Comment: Thx so much for taking time. schedule_date is by the way a CHAR(8) field. My whole statement is. I didnt use Add Dynamic Content, just copied as is in Query window.

select * from schedule_item si 
WHERE TO_DATE(si.schedule_date, 'yyyymmdd') 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('@{variables('LastDate')}', 'yyyymmdd') AND SYSDATE-1 
Error is:
ORA-00936: missing expression

If I use @concat in Add dynamic content, The whole pipeline doesnt work, not just this step.
The error message isnt really very helpful. 

By the way similar statement when run against the SQL Server, run fine without any problem.

Comment: The statement using dynamic content was:
@concat('select * from schedule_item si where si.schedule_date between ', '@{variables(StartDate)}' , ' AND ' , '@{variables(EndDate)}' )

But with this, whole pipeline errors, not just this step.steps before dont work either.